# Letter js delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a plugin called [Letter js](https://www.html5andbeyond.com/letter-by-letter-js-jquery-plugin-animated-text-plugin/) to animate a four paragraphs using html jQuery and CSS.

The plugin works great but I have an issue trying to delay the animation of each paragraph i.e. paragraph 1 should start after 1 second, paragraph 2 should start after 2 seconds with other words making each paragraph appear gradually.

I tried adding the delay function after content but that didn't work, can anybody help?

```js
// The plugin js (l-by-l.min.js) file is the following:
! function(e) {
  e.fn.lbyl = function(n) {
    {
      var t = e.extend({
          content: "",
          speed: 10,
          type: "fade",
          fadeSpeed: 500,
          finished: function() {}
        }, n),
        d = e(this),
        s = [],
        i = t.content;
      e(this).length
    }
    d.empty(), d.attr("data-time", i.length * t.speed);
    for (var p = 0; p < i.length; p++) s.push(i[p]);
    e.each(s, function(e, n) {
      d.append('<span style="display: none;">' + n + "</span>"), setTimeout(function() {
        "show" == t.type ? d.find("span:eq(" + e + ")").show() : "fade" == t.type && d.find("span:eq(" + e + ")").fadeIn(t.fadeSpeed)
      }, e * t.speed)
    }), setTimeout(function() {
      t.finished()
    }, i.length * t.speed)
  }
}(jQuery);

// My Script is the following:

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".welcome_Text1_dk").lbyl({
    content: "this is paragraph one",
    speed: 100, //time between each new letter being added
    type: 'fade', // 'show' or 'fade'
    fadeSpeed: 500, // Only relevant when the 'type' is set to 'fade'
    finished: function() {
        console.log('finished')
      } // Finished Callback
  })
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".welcome_Text2_dk").lbyl({
    content: "this is paragraph two",
    speed: 100, //time between each new letter being added
    type: 'fade', // 'show' or 'fade'
    fadeSpeed: 500, // Only relevant when the 'type' is set to 'fade'
    finished: function() {
        console.log('finished')
      } // Finished Callback
  })
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".welcome_Text3_dk").lbyl({
    content: "this is paragraph three",
    speed: 100, //time between each new letter being added
    type: 'fade', // 'show' or 'fade'
    fadeSpeed: 500, // Only relevant when the 'type' is set to 'fade'
    finished: function() {
        console.log('finished')
      } // Finished Callback
  })
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".welcome_Text4_dk").lbyl({
    content: "this is paragraph four",
    speed: 100, //time between each new letter being added
    type: 'fade', // 'show' or 'fade'
    fadeSpeed: 500, // Only relevant when the 'type' is set to 'fade'
    finished: function() {
        console.log('finished')
      } // Finished Callback
  })
});
```

```css
#home_dk {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #fff;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
#welcome_Text_Wrapper_dk {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: auto;
}
.welcome_Text1_dk,
.welcome_Text2_dk,
.welcome_Text3_dk {
  color: #b6b69c;
  font-size: 2.6em;
  font-family: "SuperGroteskWebPro-Bold W01 Rg";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.welcome_Text4_dk {
  color: #b6b69c;
  font-size: 2.6em;
  font-family: 'FF_Super_Grotesk';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home_dk">

  <article id="welcome_Text_Wrapper_dk">

    <div class="welcome_Text1_dk"></div>
    <div class="welcome_Text2_dk"></div>
    <div class="welcome_Text3_dk"></div>
    <div class="welcome_Text4_dk"></div>

  </article>

</div>
```

Comment: So the change is on the (l-by-l.min.js) file?

Comment: Where do i put the time? could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// The plugin js (l-by-l.min.js) file is the following:
! function(e) {
  e.fn.lbyl = function(n) {
    {
      var t = e.extend({
          content: "",
          speed: 10,
          type: "fade",
          fadeSpeed: 500,
          finished: function() {}
        }, n),
        d = e(this),
        s = [],
        i = t.content;
      e(this).length
    }
    d.empty(), d.attr("data-time", i.length * t.speed);
    for (var p = 0; p < i.length; p++) s.push(i[p]);
    e.each(s, function(e, n) {
      d.append('<span style="display: none;">' + n + "</span>"), setTimeout(function() {
        "show" == t.type ? d.find("span:eq(" + e + ")").show() : "fade" == t.type && d.find("span:eq(" + e + ")").fadeIn(t.fadeSpeed)
      }, e * t.speed)
    }), setTimeout(function() {
      t.finished()
    }, i.length * t.speed)
  }
}(jQuery);

// My Script is the following:

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // create an array of paragraphs
  var myParagraphs = [{
    selector: ".welcome_Text1_dk",
    content: "this is paragraph one"
  }, {
    selector: ".welcome_Text2_dk",
    content: "this is paragraph two"
  }, {
    selector: ".welcome_Text3_dk",
    content: "this is paragraph three"
  }, {
    selector: ".welcome_Text4_dk",
    content: "this is paragraph four"
  }];

  // loops it
  for (let i = 0; i < myParagraphs.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(myParagraphs[i].selector).lbyl({
        content: myParagraphs[i].content,
        speed: 100, //time between each new letter being added
        type: 'fade', // 'show' or 'fade'
        fadeSpeed: 500, // Only relevant when the 'type' is set to 'fade'
        finished: function() {
            console.log('finished')
          } // Finished Callback
      });
    }, 1000 * i);
  }

});
```

```css
#home_dk {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #fff;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
#welcome_Text_Wrapper_dk {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: auto;
}
.welcome_Text1_dk,
.welcome_Text2_dk,
.welcome_Text3_dk {
  color: #b6b69c;
  font-size: 2.6em;
  font-family: "SuperGroteskWebPro-Bold W01 Rg";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.welcome_Text4_dk {
  color: #b6b69c;
  font-size: 2.6em;
  font-family: 'FF_Super_Grotesk';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home_dk">

  <article id="welcome_Text_Wrapper_dk">

    <div class="welcome_Text1_dk"></div>
    <div class="welcome_Text2_dk"></div>
    <div class="welcome_Text3_dk"></div>
    <div class="welcome_Text4_dk"></div>

  </article>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you to you both, I appreciate your help!

Comment: happy to help, just so you know you don't need both the `l-by-l.js` and the `l-by-l.min.js`, they are both the same script, one is just minified. also, please don;t forget to checkmark whichever answer you liked best. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setTimeout()` function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // run first one here
    setTimeout(function(){
        // do the second one here
    }, 1000); // in milliseconds; 1 second
    setTimeout(function(){
        // do the third one
    }, 2000); // in milliseconds; 2 second
    setTimeout(function(){
        // do the fourth one here
    }, 3000); // in milliseconds; 3 second
    // etc.
});
```